# Flutter file explorer not working with file_picker

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Sorry, i'm a newbie to flutter.
I've created a Button, it should run the following function (as i thought, this should also open the file explorer) but it doesn't work. The Button is there, but nothing more is happening if its pressed.

```
  Padding newPadding() {
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, bottom: 20.0),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed:_openFileExplorer,
          child: const Text("Open File picker"),
                ),
              );
  }

FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

    if (result != null) {
      PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
      print(file.path);
    }    
    else {
  // User canceled the picker
  } 
}
```

What have i forgot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IOS add the following steps in POD file.

Add the below line on **project root/ios/Podfile** before the line target `'Runner' do.`

```
Pod::PICKER_MEDIA = false, resp. Pod::PICKER_AUDIO = false, resp. Pod::PICKER_DOCUMENT = false
```

After added, the code should look like this

```
Pod::PICKER_MEDIA = false, resp. Pod::PICKER_AUDIO = false, resp. Pod::PICKER_DOCUMENT = false
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
```

Answer (score 0):

file_picker package needs some steps to work fine on ios.

Please check the setup instructions in the link below:

[file_picker ios setup](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/Setup#--ios)

Comment: I've already added some of them to Info.plst
like 
```
<dict>
 <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
     <string>fetch</string>
     <string>remote-notification</string>
 </array>
 <key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
 <true/>
 <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
 <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Can you please capture the console log when you press the button @FloSojer

Comment: flutter: [MethodChannelFilePicker] Unsupported operation. Method not found. The exception thrown was: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method any on channel miguelruivo.flutter.plugins.filepicker)

Comment: I suggest you to 'flutter clean' your project and then 'flutter pub get' and 'flutter run' again.

Comment: i did it - i still get the same Error